# How can I loop through each character of a string?

Tags: c

What I am trying to do , is take a name as an output file and then a string from whic I want to fprintf each character one at a time into the output file.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
char* outputName;
char* input;
printf("Type in the name of the output file: ");
scanf("%s",outputName);
FILE *outputFile = fopen(outputName , "w");
printf("type something: ");
scanf("%s", input);
int i;
for( i = 0; i < sizeof(input)/sizeof(input[0]) ; i++ ){
     fprintf(outputFile,"%c" ,input[i]);
   }
   fclose(outputFile);
   return 0;
}
```

When I run it asks for the output file name and then it crashes. What am I doing wrong?

By the way I am completely new to C .
Any help appreciated.

Comment: 0) An area for storing input not ensured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof(input)/sizeof(input[0])` won't work here because `input` is a pointer, so `sizeof(input)` will just give the size of a pointer, not the size of the array being pointed to.

Use `strlen`, which calculates the numbers of characters until a null terminator:

```
for( i = 0; i < strlen(input) ; i++ ){
```

---

Btw you also forgot to allocate memory to `input` and `outputName`. To fix it:

```
char outputName[n];
char input[n];
```

where `n` is some magic number denoting the number of characters you can store in the C-string including the terminating null character.

Note that this approach (using arrays instead of pointers) makes `sizeof(input)/sizeof(input[0])` work as you intended.

Comment: I did what you said but now it doesn't store the characters in the outputfile

Answer (score 1):

`char* outputName` and `char* input` are just pointers, that do not point to any valid memory.

Instead you should have a character array where you can store your characters.

example:

```
char outputName[100];
char input[100];
```